# How to move a value up to a key, and remove a key. Array manipulation

Tags: php

I'm trying to change my array from this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [BID_OPEN] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0.718282
            )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [BID_CLOSE] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1.654545
            )
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [BID_OPEN] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1.654878
            )
    )
)
```

in to this:

```
Array
(
    [BID_OPEN]
    (
        [0] => 0.718282
        [1] => 1.654878
    )
    [BID_CLOSE]
    (
        [0] => 1.654545
        [1] => 1.645845
    )
)
```

I'm not sure how to begin. My code:

```
foreach($array as $keys=>$values)
{

    if(!empty($array [$c]['BID_OPEN']))
    {
        $inital_part1 = array("BID_OPEN", $array [$c]['BID_OPEN']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '';
    }
    if(!empty($array [$c]['BID_CLOSE']))
    {
        $inital_part2 = array("BID_CLOSE", $array [$c]['BID_CLOSE']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '';
    }
    $array1[] = $inital_part1;
    $array1[] = $inital_part2;
    $c++;
}
```

I seem to get double outputs, so the foreach when I build arrays is giving me two times the required output. Google reckons it's because I have an array in my array somewhere but I'm precisely sure I don't.

The array came from an object stdclass and I don't know what that is, have googled but haven't found anything useful. Also I'm able to get some figures but only the initial values are correct, the rest of the data doesn't seem to come through. No doubt it's because I used an index[0] to get it working.

After hours any help would be great thanks.

Comment: That desired result makes no sense, since one array cannot contain the same key twice.

Comment: I would've though that that would be surpassed by the naught on top of it, allowing a user to get max(array[0][BID_OPEN]) (the highest number of the set)? Hmm.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of data structure  `[0] ( [BID_OPEN] => 0.718282 [BID_OPEN] => 1.654878 )` is supposed to represent. The closest it looks like is an array with two keys, both of which have the same name.

Comment: Would you like to have this kind of result? 
Array
(
    [BID_OPEN] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.718282
            [1] => 1.654878
        )

    [BID_CLOSE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.654545
            [1] => 1.645845
        )

)

Comment: array_merge_recursive(...$arr) ?

Comment: Divyesh, yes please. How to get that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have told us everything about your input array it can be done quite simply like this

```
<?php

$in = [ ['BID_OPEN' => [0.718282]],
        ['BID_CLOSE' => [1.654545]],
        ['BID_OPEN' => [1.654878]]
      ];
print_r($in);

$new = [];  // new array we are building

foreach ($in as $abid) {
    if (array_key_exists('BID_OPEN', $abid) ) {
        $new['BID_OPEN'][] = $abid['BID_OPEN'][0];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('BID_CLOSE', $abid) ) {
        $new['BID_CLOSE'][] = $abid['BID_CLOSE'][0];
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

THE INPUT ARRAY: Is like yours

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [BID_OPEN] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.718282
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [BID_CLOSE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1.654545
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [BID_OPEN] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1.654878
                )

        )

)
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [BID_OPEN] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.718282
            [1] => 1.654878
        )

    [BID_CLOSE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.654545
        )

)
```

Comment: I misunderstand, how am I getting the initial array that you've presented defined as $in? The array that I'm dealing with is at the top of my question. It's a little different. Granted that $in array is actually what was originally posted as a requested answer, but am I missing a step?

Comment: I think the test array I built in the answer is just like the one you specified in your question

Comment: The one in my question has numerical array keys in front of it. I've been trying for hours, and I just don't seem to be able to reduce those numerical keys so that I get an array like the one you posted. I'm not sure how to.

Comment: The output from my `print_r($in)` looks just like your example. If your actual array is different then please post the actual input array you are dealing with.... _In your question_

Comment: My input array is this:  `[0] => Array([BID_OPEN] => Array([0] => 0.718282 ) ) [1] => Array` which is a bit different from your $in ney? In my array I have added numerical keys [0], and [1] and etc above the [BID_OPEN] keys. I'm talking about the array I have to input, not output.

Comment: @AceThanks Numeric array indexes are added implicitly, they don't need to be defined explicitly.  What you are showing is a `var_dump()` output, which shows all keys/indexes.  The array that Riggs is using is the same as yours.

Comment: I don't understand. How? How would a person get the kind of output shown in Riggs's example from what I have displayed at the top of my question??

Comment: @AceThanks Check out the code [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62778ed570079a2df34366d94432c8b6f9b44b27) and [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a05bf9ed4ae8c27e75e820fd11e4b6a87f1e0fe4).  The first uses the code above to create `$in`.  The second one uses a long-hand way of creating the array.  Run the code in both and you will see that the result of each is the same, and that result is also the same as your original array.

Comment: @AceThanks Have you tried to run the code against your array? If so, if you do not get what I did, please explain what the issue is. _I did actually test this code before submitting the answer_ The outputs are real

Comment: "Numeric array indexes are added implicitly, they don't need to be defined explicitly" I had no notion! I've been striving to remove these annoying numerical key indexes for a long time. So that's great news. I've marked your answer as correct even though I came up with my own solution. So you're saying I can manipulate arrays irrespective of the numerical key indexes altogether?

Comment: Actually, I just spotted a problem. The output is 2 fold of that expected. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = 0;
$array1['BID_OPEN'] = [];
$array2['BID_CLOSE'] = [];
foreach($vartttttt as $tunips=>$ert)
{

    $d = 0;
    foreach($ert as $erts=>$val)
    {
        //$array[] = $erts;
        if($erts == 'BID_OPEN')
        {
            array_push($array1['BID_OPEN'], $val[0]);
        }
        if($erts == 'BID_CLOSE')
        {
            array_push($array2['BID_CLOSE'], $val[0]);
        }
        $d++;
    }
    $c++;
}
$array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```